# Doctrine ODM with symfony 3.0.*

Tags: composer-php, doctrine-odm, symfony

i'm trying to install the Dotrine ODM bundle but composer returns

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

my `composer.json` file looks like this :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
     "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0"
},
```

According to the full composer error message (*see below*), doctrine ODM needs symfony2.8.2 max version.

Does it mean the bundle is not symfony3.0.*-ready yet or am i missing something (i.e composer configs...)

**full composer log :**

```html
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 3.0.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 3.0.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle v3.0.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.36|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.37|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ~3.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[3.0.1, 3.0.2, v3.0.0].
```

Comment: odm for S3 is still in beta.  Try adjusting your composer.json minimum-stability setting. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability.  Then remove the odm lines from the file and composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle to get the correct version.

Comment: i downgraded to symfony2.8 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just do :

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "@dev"
```

and specify the dev flag.

Then do:

```
$ php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

The dev version should be functional but expect things to change as code is being constantly applied.